# Can you avoid specifying a namespace when invoking a class which uses one?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-7

I have an older framework which doesn't implement namespaces. If i try to slowly introduce namespaces, by first declaring one at top of a class declaration, then any invokation of that class will now fail, because it isn't invoked through its namespace. Even though the class file is already included, and there isn't (or so i thought) a need for PHP to know the namespace.

It seems PHP doesn't care that it **can** find a class by the name `Foo`, because if `Foo` is under a namespace, then it will always mandate that you have to specify the namespace as well.

As a simple test, i put this in one file:

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

class Foo {
    function bar(): void {
        print "Hello world.";
    }
}
```

And this in another:

```php
<?php

include "Foo.php";

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

It gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo' not found

So my question is, can this behaviour be avoided (with some configuration options maybe) to ease the slow transition from a framework that doesn't use namespaces into one that does, or would I have to replace all invokations of all the classes at once before it becomes usable? Are there any hacky alternatives?

Comment: You could try to use `class_alias()` to alias namespaced class to old name without namespace, but this will not help you whit moving your codebase to namespaces, it will only create bigger mess. You should should fix all usages of this class by adding `use Test\Foo;` to all files that use this class (and possible handle cases where class name was defined as string, since `use` keyword does not affect them. There should be tools that may help automate this (PhpStorm for example is able to rename class and fix all usages).

Comment: I also find this behavior annoying

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the "path" of your class like this :

```php
<?php

use Test\Foo;

include "foo.class.php";

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

I don't see another solution...

For more information about Use : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score -1):

you lost namespace :)

```
$foo = new \Test\Foo();
```